# 403 Forbidden when hitting Azure API Management with Azure Function Backend

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I'm getting 403 Forbidden error when hitting Azure Functions via API Management. Just to be clear, I don't have any Authentication/Authorization in the function but Authorization Level is set to Function Level.

I can hit the function directly using the Function key.
I can also hit the API Management and getting response when mocking was enabled so the error is coming out of the function. I can verify that the function key is being passed by API management to the backend function.

Noticed that this only happens when the function was deployed using ARM.

Comment: what do you mean using ARM? there is no other way to deploy it

Comment: If I understand correctly, this doesn't seem to be an issue with APIM, but rather with your Azure function. In that case, you might need to remove the APIM tag.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I mean Azure Resource Manager

Comment: @PieterVandenheede Yes you are right. I just found out that our ARM template added some IP whitelist that is why I was able to hit the functions directly. I just added the IP address of APIM and it worked. Thanks all for your time!

Comment: If it is resolved, please add an answer here that will help more communities who have that same issue easily to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our Azure Function was deployed with IP restrictions and APIM IP was not present there. After adding APIM IP address thru Function's **Platform Features** > **Networking Group** > **Networking** > **Configure IP Restriction**, 403 errors were gone.